# Comparing old dict list with new dict list to find the differences across keys and values of all list objects

Tags: python, dictionary, parameter-passing

There are tons of Q&A on StackOverflow regarding comparing direct `old dict` to `new dict`,

- I would like to compare an old list of dicts with a new list of dicts and find what's removed, added, updated.

```
old_dict = [{'name':'john','age':10},{'name':'cena','age':26},{'name':'tom','age':24}]
new_dict = [{'name':'cena','age':26},{'name':'john','age':13},{'name':'henry','age':32},{'name':'steave','age':50}]
```

I would like to pass `old_dict` & `new_dict` as arguments to the function where comparing of keys, values across all list-objects & that function would return the following fields

```
return updated_key_val,added_key_val,removed_new_key_val
```

```
print(updated_key_val)
>> [{'name':'john','age':13}] ### age value updated from 10 to 13

print(added_key_val)
>> [{'name':'henry','age':32},{'name':'steave','age':50}] ## old results doesn't had this 2 dicts so this are new dicts

print(removed_new_key_val)
>> [{'name':'tom','age':24}] ## this has been removed in newer results
```

Comment: What did you learn from the tons of questions you found? What is stopping you from solving your problem?

Comment: What if someone adds a dict to one of the dicts in the list of dicts (generating a nested dict structure)? I.e. ```old_dict[0].update({"weight":"val1", "height":"val2"})```? Is nesting allowed?

Answer (score 1):

Since each dictionary is being considered equal when the 'name' field is equal, you can make an index of those old names to the entries, then keep track of updated, added, and removed after one iteration over the new entries

```
def entries_diff(old_entries, new_entries):
    updated, added = [], []
    old_index = {e['name']: e for e in old_entries}
    for e in new_entries:
        name = e['name']
        if name not in old_index:
            added.append(e)
        else:
            old = old_index[name]
            if old != e:
                updated.append(e)
            del old_index[name]

    removed = list(old_index.values())
    return updated, added, removed
```

which gives the expected result on your dummy data.